# The English Tourist

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

"A tourist want to go from Liverpool to Sydney, visiting a number of other cities in the process.

for each pair of cities, he can travel by *car*, *train* or *ferry*, each option has a **Cost** and **Time**.

the goal is to go to syndey,traversing all cities in the process whilst keeping the time and cost to a  minimum."

1-how do i verify that this problem is NP? given total time **T** and total cost **C**? 
i.e: if i have 5 nodes, connected by 4 edges,
each edge has 3 options (car,ferry,train)
each option has Cost and time

how do i process the constraints? do i just try all permutations ?

2-i need guidance on actual solution, i do realize this is a subset of the [Minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) , but now i have 2 constraints, time and cost..how to tackle that ?

Comment: Sounds a bit like homework to me....

Comment: Agree - definitely homework; in addition, he should explicitly point what his solution is and where he's stuck.

Comment: and i didnt do that? where did i say i need actual implementation?
i merely asked for guidance

and im a she, not a he :)

Comment: You want to minimize the cost or the time? you have to define an order relation between pairs of (time,cost).

Comment: both, to get the guy to his destination in minimum cost AND time possible.

Comment: 4 edges * 3 options each = 12 edges. I would proceed by simple expansion by 1 arc on each pulse, eliminating the cycles of course, keeping the queues sorted by time (and in separate run, by cost). Then watch what arrives at Sidney, while sorting the arrivals too. But if you really have 4 edges between 5 nodes, you only have 4 3-way splits (81 paths) and no cycles in your tree.

Comment: no such thing both cost AND time. to go by bicycle is cheapest, to go by plain is fastest.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini "he"'s a she. :) Haven't you heard about Salma Hayek? If not, the identicon is right there. :)

Comment: You need to define, if not given as part of the exercise, what is your way of measuring cost versus time. As @WillNess said both can not be mínimum at the same time. Challenge your teacher if this is not defined or told not to be required.

Comment: how do you define which combination of cost and time is better?

Comment: its not given picarus, but i think it has something to do with operation research also, the kind of (how to maximize your profit while cutting your losses) kinda thing, i just cant wrap my head around it!

Comment: I am not sure this is in NP. I don't believe there is a way to verify that you have minimized cost and time (even if you knew what this means) in polynomial time. You could certainly reduce TSP to this showing that this is at least NP-Hard.

Comment: @WillNess apologies :) did not really look at the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem is solved with the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)